# Add WCF Service From Another Solution

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, reference, poco

I seem to be confusing myself the more I dig around the internet for help on this so any advice is really appreciated...

I'm simply trying to reference a service from Solution **A** in Solution **B**. I have the service up and running and consumed in Solution **A**. I deployed the service and front end to our `Dev`environment and verified its working. So now I want to consume the service I deployed from Solution **A** in Solution **B**.

I have this service url: `https://Domain/Common/CommonService.svc/ws` that I want to consume in Solution **B**.

I'm confused at how I should configure it...

Do I need to allow serviceMetadata? I'm assuming yes or how else will it make the reference.

I referenced Solution **A**'s `DLL` `Common.Domain.Entities` that has all the POCOs in Solution **B**.

I'm just not sure how I'm supposed to do this, so any point in the right direction would be nice. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable the MEX endpoint for the service (it's enabled by default) and add a Service Reference to the Service Hosted by Solution A to your project consuming the service in Solution B. A service reference can be added in Visual Studio by right-clicking the project node in Visual Studio.

Comment: Well right, but do I want to leave the mex endpoint enabled even in production, because new applications will need to consume the service as well?

Comment: @Jisaak - Leaving the MEX endpoint active in production is a call you would have to make to fit your needs. Exposing it to the public allows others to generate clients for your service automatically. Is that a need for your project? It also tells the world what data types your service expects, which is a potential security issue, if your service is private in nature. If it is a private service then what I typically do is have a development server running within the LAN/firewall that has MEX on that I use to gen a client, then change the URL to prod which does not have MEX enabled.

Comment: Thanks for the added information. I think that will be our strategy as well... Allow get in DEV and QA environments, but close it in Production. Thanks again for the good advice and insight.